# Flutter Network Image does not fit in Circular Avatar

Tags: image, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to retrieve bunch of images from an api. I want the images to be displayed in Circular form so I am using `CircleAvatar` Widget, but I keep getting images in square format.
 Here is a screenshot of images

[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
ListTile(leading: CircleAvatar(child: Image.network("${snapshot.data.hitsList[index].previewUrl}",fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,)),),
```

I tryied using all the properties of `BoxFit` like `cover`, `contain`,`fitWidth`,`fitHeight` etc but none of them works.

Comment: Have you tried `fit: BoxFit.cover`?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

This Will Work : You need to use `backgroundImage:`property in order to fit it in Circle.

```
CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30.0,
                backgroundImage:
                    NetworkImage("${snapshot.data.hitsList[index].previewUrl}"),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              )
```

To Check with Dummy Placeholder:

```
CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30.0,
                backgroundImage:
                    NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              )
```

Comment: and what about an image from storage, Image.file(Image.file(File file)). Can CircleAvatar handle it?

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan yes. You can use AssetImage in backgroundImage property.

Comment: Sometimes you will want to use this with FadeInImage like myself...in which case the best way to do it is wrapping it in a ClipOval widget...here is a snippet:

```CircleAvatar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      child: ClipOval(
        child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder: placeholderPath,
          image: imageUrl,
        ),
      ),
    );```

Answer (score 107):

Had a similar problem in the `AppBar` actions widget list.

This worked for me:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 18,
    child: ClipOval(
        child: Image.network(
          'image-url',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 52):

If you don't want to use `CircleAvatar`, here is how you can do it.

```
ClipOval(
  child: Image.network(
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

Comment: why someone wouldn't try circle avatar

Comment: @AsbahRiyas because image doesnt fill the available space. Try to use big image in very small Circle Avatar then you will know what's the problem is.

Comment: A reason for me to not use the CircleAvatar, was that it animates the background colors, which I didn't want. In other words, this solution is perfect for me, thanks.

Comment: Nice worked fine

Answer (score 23):

if someone intends to create bordered circular image try this.

Using `ClipOval` widget is not perfect solution because if images are not square result will be elliptic.

```
CircleAvatar(radius: (52),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(50),
              child: Image.asset("assets/pictures/profile.png"),
            )
        )
```

`ClipRRect` widget prevents image to overflow `CircleAvatar` widget.

Comment: Actually the most perfect implementation. Works fine for all image sizes and doesn't warp the image in any way. Thanks

Comment: Don't use Clips unless necessary, which in this case it isn't. Clips can be more expensive than changing the border radius directly: https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices

Answer (score 14):

**simply use** `backgroundImage` inside `CircleAvatar`

```
 CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/dia.jpg",),
    ),
```

Comment: This isn't working for network images for me, any idea why?

Answer (score 13):

You will need to use `NetworkImage`, `AssetImage`, `FileImage`, `MemoryImage` or something similar. You can't directly use `Image.network`, `Image.asset` or similar due to how Flutter architects its image classes.

An example:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 100.0,
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(...),
)
```

`backgroundImage` in `CircleAvatar` expects to receive an `ImageProvider` as a parameter. However, `Image.network` and others don't directly extend the `ImageProvider` class, they merely extend the `StatefulWidget` class, even though they use `NetworkImage` inside. That is why you see in the other answers that `ClipOval` or `ClipRRect` is being used. These classes accept a `Widget` and so they're not as particular as `CircleAvatar` and similar classes are.

Instead of these workarounds, therefore, for `CircleAvatar`, you should use `NetworkImage` and similar classes and for widgets that expect just a `Widget`, you can use `Image.network` and similar.

Another reason not to use clips is that they can be more expensive than changing the border radii directly: https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices

Answer (score 6):

this work for me

```
   CircleAvatar(
                  child:  ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                      child:Image.network("http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg-1024x683.jpg"),
                ),),
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 CircleAvatar(
        radius: 26,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: ClipOval(
          child: _bytesImage == null
              ? new Text('No image value.')
              : Image.memory(
                  _bytesImage,
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is trying to fit a circular image in app bar actions. Try below solution it should work.

```
         Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/500'),

              ),
            ),
          )
```

AspectRatio first tries the largest width permitted by the layout constraints(here the appbar). If I remove the padding image radius will be of appbar size. So add padding to control the size of circular image.

Comment: Exactly the solution is.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your CircleAvatar widget under Stack widget.

```
 return Stack(
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 50.0,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/0c/eb/c3/0cebc3e2a01fe5abcff9f68e9d2a06e4.jpg'),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem

```
CircleAvatar(
             radius: 30.0,
             backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageURL),
             backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
             ));
```

fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a round picture with a shadow:

```
child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 1/1,
    child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(
            10.0
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
            boxShadow:[
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(60, 0, 0, 0),
                  blurRadius: 5.0,
                  offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0)
              )
            ],
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                image: NetworkImage(user.image)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  ClipOval(
     child: Image.asset(
      'assets/dummy.jpg',
       fit: BoxFit.contain,
       matchTextDirection: true,
       height: 50,
   ))
```

Comment: While this code may/may no solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Use combination of `width/height`, `fit` and wrap image in `ClipOval` like below:

```
CircleAvatar(
    child: ClipOval(
        child: Image.network(
            _photo,
            width: 120,
            fit: BoxFit.fill
        ),
    ),
    radius: 50,
),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show your image covering whole width of circle avatar then you can use it like this way. And if your image didnot load then it will show default person icon.

```
 CircleAvatar(
              child: ClipOval(
                                  child: Center(
                                child: _image == null
                                    ? Icon(
                                        Icons.person,
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                        size: 100,
                                      )
                                    : Image.file(
                                        _image,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ),

                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Using clipoval in circle avatar will make it elliptical.
But this fixed this issue.

```
CircleAvatar(

             radius:25.0,

             backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        '${image_url}',


                        ),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                    CachedNetworkImage(
                        placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                            new Icon(Icons.error),
                        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                            width: 60.0,
                            height: 60.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider,
                                    fit: BoxFit.contain))),
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        imageUrl:
                            "${Constants.MEDIA_LINK}${state.review.company.logo}"),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp7()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 50,
                      // backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
                          radius: 50,
                          // child: Image.asset("assets/images/nophotoMale.png")
                          backgroundImage:
                              AssetImage("assets/images/nophotoMale.png")),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Yeah Sure I will Add

Answer (score 1):

Below worked in my case:

```
child: new CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: ClipRect(
          child: Image.network(
            'url-to-image',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

It took a few tries to figure this one out.. All these answers did not help me. In the end picture that I inserted into the circle avatar was stretched out to the boundaries of the container that was 2 instances above it. Maybe there are are people who, after going through the answers here, still have the problem that I had. I solved the constraint issue with a [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html)

```
             GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => getImage(),
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Container(
                          width: 140,
                          height: 160,
                          child: FittedBox(
                            child: picture(),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
```

This is the code for the picture() that I use. I think that the container inside the picture() is not necessary anymore, try it yourself :)

```
Widget picture() {
if (_image == null) {
  return CircleAvatar(
      radius: 70,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.person,
        size: 150,
        color: Colors.grey[900],
      ));
} else {
  return Container(
    width: 140,
    height: 140,
    child: CircleAvatar(
      radius: 70,
      backgroundImage: FileImage(_image),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this solution you can resize the image by container and clip image by clip Oval then add shadow to the image by card.

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Card(
      elevation: 5,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(45.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Container(
        child: ClipOval(
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '{image-url}',
          imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: imageProvider,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
            height: 5,
            width: 5,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
            ),
          ),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
        )),
      ),
    ),
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is work for me. I think that best way*

```
           CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
                          child: Container(
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: 
                            BoxShape.circle),
                            child: const CachedNetworkImage(
                              url: "https://www.yourimage.com",
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do it is like this:

```dart
class CircleImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget backgroundImage;
  final double radius;
  final Color colorBask;
  const CircleImage({super.key, required this.backgroundImage, required this.radius, required this.colorBask});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
      width: radius,
      height: radius,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: colorBask,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(radius/5),
          width: radius/2,
          height: radius/2,
          child:  backgroundImage,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

call like this:

```dart
            CircleImage(
              radius: 60.0,
              colorBask: colorScheme.surface,
              backgroundImage: Image.asset(
                'assets/img.png',
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Came here as I also had the issue with CirclAvatar and AppBar, where the image would stretch in height. Instead of a radius, as I'm not able to provide it with the component I'm using, I just wrapped the image with a colum when used in appbar. This makes the image not stretch in height. This way I can always control size from the outside too

```
Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 40, width: 40, child: ProfileBadge(),),
                ],
              )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use AvatarView lib https://pub.dev/packages/avatar_view which provides the functionality to show network/asset images in circular/rectangular form.

To use add below dependency

```
dependencies:
  avatar_view: ^1.0.0+3
```

**Example:**

```
        AvatarView(
                  radius: 60,
                  borderColor: Colors.yellow,
                  avatarType: AvatarType.CIRCLE,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  imagePath:
                  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/415829/pexels-photo-415829.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-415829.jpg",
                  placeHolder: Container(
                    child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 50,),
                  ),
                  errorWidget: Container(
                    child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 50,),
                  ),
                ),
```

It also provide funtionality to add borders around widget, for more example visit above link

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me

```
Transform.scale(
        scale: 0.6,
        child: ClipOval(
          child: Image.network(
            <IMAGE URL HERE>,
          ),
        ),
      )
```