# CircleAvatar not showing circular image

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using CicleAvatar to show my avatar but it is not showing circular shape. 
Here is my code

```
  //Circle Image
  Widget circularImage(){
    return new CircleAvatar(
        radius: 45,
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: this.strImageURL,
          placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
        )
    );
  }
```

Comment: You need to use backgroundImage:property in order to fit it in Circle.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514007/10269042

Comment: @anmol.majhail you should make your comment an answer, since that is the proper actual answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can wrap your cachedNetworkImage in ClipRRect widget like this:

```
Widget circularImage(){
    return CircleAvatar(
        radius: 45,
        child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: this.strImageURL,
              placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error),
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: @CodeHunter Glad I was able to help! Accepting my answer would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`ClipOval` can be used, this Creates an oval-shaped clip.
If [clipper] is null, the oval will be inscribed into the layout size and
position of the child.

```
ClipOval(
  child: Image.asset(
    "image.png",
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 50.0,
    height: 50.0,
  )
),
```