# How to give a CircleAvatar an image from assets

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I'm doing some testing with the CircleAvatar. I know that the background image would normally be obtained from the network, which is what the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) shows:

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(userAvatarUrl),
)
```

However, for testing purposes I just want to use asset images. I can't do this

```
leading: CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: Image.asset('assets/horse.png'),
)
```

because as the error says

> The argument type `Image` can't be assigned to the parameter type `ImageProvider`.

How do I give an assets image to `ImageProvider`?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use child property from CircleAvatar:

```
  CircleAvatar(
      child: Image.asset('assets/horse.png'),
   );
```

or if you want to use the backgroundImage property use the asset provider.

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/horse.png'),
);
```

Comment: Ah, `AssetImage` is an `ImageProvider`. This works better than setting the `child` because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53513456/3681880) where the image isn't clipped to the circle size.

Comment: but what to do if image is not scaling, if image too big how to scale?

Comment: backgroundImage: AssetImage is perfect for me

Answer (score 3):

Use [avatar_view](https://pub.dev/packages/avatar_view)

```
           /// 1. Circular AvatarView Without Border
            AvatarView(
              radius: 60,
              borderColor: Colors.yellow,
              isOnlyText: false,
              text: Text('C', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50),),
              avatarType: AvatarType.CIRCLE,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              imagePath: "assets/image_1.png",
              placeHolder: Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 50,),
              ),
              errorWidget: Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 50,),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16,),
            /// 2. Circular AvatarView With Border
            AvatarView(
              radius: 60,
              borderWidth: 8,
              borderColor: Colors.yellow,
              avatarType: AvatarType.CIRCLE,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              imagePath: "assets/image_1.png",
              placeHolder: Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 50,),
              ),
              errorWidget: Container(
                child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 50,),
              ),
            ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Native solutions should be preferred over third party plugins

Answer (score -1):

```
AvatarView(
  radius: 60,
  borderWidth: 8,
  borderColor: Colors.yellow,
  avatarType: AvatarType.CIRCLE,
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  imagePath: "assets/image_1.png",
  placeHolder: Container(
    child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 50,),
  ),
  errorWidget: Container(
    child: Icon(Icons.error, size: 50,),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Add more information like the package name, and other details. Thanks