# flutter Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

Tags: image, flutter, dart

can someone help me with this error? I have this circle avatar, in it I have a background image with an image coming from the api, the image appears on the screen but it doesn't consume I have an exeption

my circle avatar the image appears on screen

```
child: Obx(() {
                    return CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        controller.urlImagem.value.toString(),
                      ),
                      maxRadius: 100,
                    );
```

this is the error:

```
══════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2662:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2573:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:89
#3      NetworkImage.load
package:flutter/…/painting/_network_image_io.dart:50
#4      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:505
#5      ImageCache.putIfAbsent
package:flutter/…/painting/image_cache.dart:380
#6      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:503
#7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:333
#8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:464
#9      SynchronousFuture.then
package:flutter/…/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41
#10     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:461
#14     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provide
```

this is the print of my url it is normal

```
I/flutter (11192): Resultado Instance of 'CurrentInfluencerModel'
I/flutter (11192): https://sollerassessoria-homolog.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/pessoas/21/avatar.png
```

I'm trying to solve this error because I need to put a fadeInImage.MemoryNewtwork, but when I do that I have an exception with the same name as the exeption above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513456/flutter-network-image-does-not-fit-in-circular-avatar