# Flutter CircleAvatar not showing image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get the CircleAvatar to show an image, however, it shows a blue circle. If I run the code snipped below on my mac, it shows a blue circle. If I run the code in an online compiler (Dartpad), it shows the image as expected.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/200"),
          radius: 100,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

| This is the result on my mac | This is the result on DartPad |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Flutter doctor finds no issues, flutter clean does not help, Android Studio invalidate caches / restart does not help. I am new to Flutter and Dart, so have no idea how to debug further.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Network Image does not fit in Circular Avatar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513456/flutter-network-image-does-not-fit-in-circular-avatar)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
            "https://picsum.photos/200",
          ),
          radius: 100,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: This code gives me a blue circle as well. Something must be wrong on my mac, but I do not know what?

Comment: You don't need to blue circle?

Comment: No, I want the picture just as you posted it on your results screen

Comment: Just add `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,`in `CircleAvtar()` widget check my updated answer

Comment: Is your problem is solved?

Comment: This removes the blue circle, but leaves a transparant circle. The image is still not appearing

Comment: First thing if you used `CircleAvtar()` it will display circle and your image is loading then it will be displayed and when you hear app again and again the images will be changed if any query please let me know

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, but there is still no image appearing

Comment: Can we connect Google meeting?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Any resolution?

Comment: @LelandReardon have you try my solution?

Comment: For my issue, I had to quit and restart my emulator.

Comment: @LelandReardon your issue was resolved or not?