# How do I make the app flutter logo circular instead of a square inside the circle?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface

**After doing that**, how do you make the background of the circular logo transparent?

[I am talking about the App logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNerg.png)
and here is another example :
[another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE0br.png)

- I am using Android studio

Thanks in advance

I tried many techniques but didn't know how :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but according to what I've read on other websites, I think it doesn't need a code but is about the size of the logo to upload or some special configuration.

** I have modified the post by adding a clarification :)

Comment: tried fit: BoxFit.cover ?

Comment: @Etornam, thanks for your comment but did you check the provided images ??

Comment: Please provide a sample code or code snippet

Answer (score 0):

you can try by inserting the image into the background image like this.

```
CircleAvatar(
            radius: 25.0,
            backgroundImage:
                NetworkImage('your image url'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          )
```

or you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513456/flutter-network-image-does-not-fit-in-circular-avatar)

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i am talking about the outside App logo, please check the provided image.